# C++ Sorting with Arrays and Structs and a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers, struct

I have similar homework assignment like this however with my struct it points to my arrays because it holds 99 items. How would I include the pointer so it will read from every item? Here is what I have so far.
When I try and run it, I get an error where `temp.name = ...` is.

```
struct Item
{
    string name;
    float price;
    char category;
    int numberOfPiecesInStock;
    Date lastSDate;
    Date outOfStockSinceDate;
};

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    Item *giftItems;
    ///////////MORE CODE ///////
}

void sortByItemNum(Item *giftItems, int length)
{
    Item temp;
    int i, j;


    for (i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
        temp.name = Item *giftItems[i]->name;
        temp.price = Item *giftItems[i]->price;
        temp.category = Item *giftItems[i]->category;
        temp.numberOfPiecesInStock = Item *giftItems[i]->numberOfPiecesInStock;

        j = 1;
        while (j > 0 && (temp.numberOfPiecesInStock = giftItems[j-1]->numberOfPiecesInStock > temp.numberOfPiecesInStock)
        {
            giftItems[j]->numberOfPiecesInStock = giftItems[j-1].numberOfPiecesInStock;
            j--;
        }
        // giftItems[j]->numberOfPiecesInStock = temp;
        // swap (Item temp, i, j);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you get an error. Consider reading the error message.

Comment: You say you have a similar assignment, similar to what? It would be helpful to describe the assignment. Also please include the error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `giftItems` is an array with `length` number of elements. To reference an individual item in the array, you need to use this form:

```
giftItems[i].member
```

instead of this form:

```
Item *giftItems[i]->member
```

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt to not just give you the solution...

Let's take a look:

```
temp.name = Item *giftItems[i]->name;
temp.price = Item *giftItems[i]->price;
temp.category = Item *giftItems[i]->category;
temp.numberOfPiecesInStock = Item *giftItems[i]->numberOfPiecesInStock;
```

What you are most likely getting is a casting error, due to the "Item" which you have in front of your pointers in the above assignments.

You are telling the program at runtime to cast

```
*giftItems[i]->name
```

to an Item object and then assign it to temp.name which is a string. This will definitely cause an error.